# kCustomButtonHeight undeclared

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a segmented control in the navigation bar.  Just like in the docs

```
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:
                                      [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"up.png"],
                                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"down.png"],
                                          nil]];

[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 90, kCustomButtonHeight);
```

But I get kCustomButtonHeight undeclared.  Has this been deprecated?  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`kCustomButtonHeight` is a macro the person who wrote that example code made up. It's nothing included in `UIKit` or anything. You can define it yourself, if you want, and make it anything you'd like.

```
#define kCustomButtonHeight 42
```

Answer (score 0):

This was never part of the SDK, from what I can see through Google, it seems that kCustomButtonHeight is just defined in some Apple sample code that you may have used.